# how to return 2nd row record for only 1 column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am selecting multiple column from a table, and one of the column i require to fetch record from second row. How should i specify in my query that only that 1 column need to fetch from row 2? The select statement return 2 rows, but segment 4 i need to return 2nd row value only, other column return value of row 1. How should i write it?

```
select  substrb(segment2,1,30) invtime
 ,  substrb(segment3,1,30) invoice
 ,  substrb(segment4,1,10) invdate
from error_process_log;
```

Comment: You need to be able to determine unambiguously what is meant by 2nd row. The order in which data is returned is only guaranteed by specifying an ORDER BY. Once you have that, getting the 2nd row is trivial, and using the ROW_NUMBER() analytical function is good solution.

Comment: If you are using oracle 12c, you can even use the offset clause.   SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY 1 OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY. This will get you the second row. But like @BobC said, you need to order by something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Anlaytical functions like Lead() Lag() in this scenario. Hope below illustration helps.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(a.nm,1,10),
  SUBSTR(lead(a.sn) over(order by a.sn ),1,5)
FROM
  (SELECT 1 AS seq,'avrajit' nm,'Roy1' sn FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS seq,'shubho' nm,'Roy2' sn FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS seq,'papa' nm,'Roy3' sn FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS seq,'romi' nm,'Roy4' sn FROM dual
  )a;
```

Comment: The illustration is fine, but the OP needs to understand that without something to order by, there is not really a valid concept of "2nd row".